# Load a .obj and .stl in Babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

I want to load a file, using Babylon.js, that has been uploaded by the user. I've looked around but can only find examples of loading babylon scene files.

Is there a way of loading .obj and/or .stl files directly with Babylon.js without having to convert them to .babylon files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

to reduce framework size, Babylon.js does not include file loader. But you can go there an use one of our loader: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/loaders

Comment: David, can you not also use a local conversion tool? I.e. https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters  (see the readme under the XNA-OBJ directory).   It appears you need to compile C# code, or use the ready-made binary found at that github directory.  (Will the code compile with Mono, on Linux, by the way?)

Comment: This is a option but you won't have a lot of control over the process and this will only work on windows due to xna dependency

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assetManager? It can solve your problem automatically. In plain it is only an array filled with loaded data enriched by nice Loading screen, more here: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/wiki/Using-AssetsManager

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>Babylon.js sample code assetsManager loading</title>
        <!-- Babylon.js -->
        <script src="index_subory/hand.js"></script>
        <script src="index_subory/cannon.js"></script>
        <script src="index_subory/oimo.js"></script>
        <script src="index_subory/babylon.2.0.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="index_subory/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body {
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #renderCanvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                touch-action: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:grey;color:white;font-weight:bold;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;">Pre prehliadače s WebGL: WebGL Javascript pokus v babylon.js - ovládaj šípkami na klávesnici a ťahaním myškou:<br><div style="background-color:grey;color:white;font-weight:bold;">The Pulse [Ak nevidíte video, chyba je v prehliadači, ľutujeme, možno novší to zvládne ;-) ] </div></div>
    <canvas height="782" width="1440" id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvass = $('#renderCanvas');   
        // check to see if we can do webgl
// ALERT FOR JQUERY PEEPS: canvas is a jquery obj - access the dom obj at canvas[0]
var dcanvas = canvass[0];
expmt = false;
if ("WebGLRenderingContext" in window) {
    //alert("browser at least knows what webgl is.");
}
// some browsers don't have a .getContext for canvas...
try { 
    gl = dcanvas.getContext("webgl"); 
    }catch (x){ 
        gl = null; 
        }
if (gl == null) {
    try { 
        gl = dcanvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"); 
        }catch (x){ 
            gl = null; 
            }
if (gl == null) { 
    //console.log('but can\'t speak it'); 
    }else { 
        expmt = true; //alert('webgl experimentally.'); 
        }
} else {
    //alert('webgl natively');
}

if (gl || expmt) {
//alert("loading webgl content.");
} else {
alert("CHYBA: Váš prehliadač nepodporuje WebGL, ľutujeme. (ERROR: Your browser does not support WebGL, sorry.)");
canvas.remove();
}


         if (BABYLON.Engine.isSupported()) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
        var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
        var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        var sphere1 = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("Sphere1", 1.0, 1.0, scene);
        var createScene = function () {


            // setup environment
            var light0 = new BABYLON.PointLight("Omni", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 10,80), scene);
            var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("FreeCamera", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, -30), scene);
            var light2 = new BABYLON.PointLight("Omni", new BABYLON.Vector3(10, 10, -80), scene);

            var simpleMaterial = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("texture2", scene);

            simpleMaterial.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 1, 0);//Green
            sphere1.material = simpleMaterial;
            sphere1.position.x=-4;
            sphere1.position.z=-4;
            sphere1.position.y=4.5;

            camera.position.x = -9;
            camera.position.y = 4;
            camera.position.z = -10;
            camera.rotation.x = .28;
            camera.rotation.y = .707;
            camera.rotation.z = 0;
            camera.speed = .2;
            camera.attachControl(canvas);
            var ecran = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("impact", 8, scene); 
            ecran.rotation.z = 2*Math.PI;            
            // Video material
        var videoMat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("textVid", scene);
        videoMat.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.VideoTexture("video", ["index_subory/v.ogv"], 256, scene, false);
        videoMat.backFaceCulling = false;
        ecran.material = videoMat;


            // Mirror

            //var mirror = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("Mirror", 1.0, scene);
            var mirror = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGround("gnd", 16, 16, 1, scene, true);
            // var mirror = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("Mirror", 5.0, scene);
            mirror.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -0.5, 0);
            mirror.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mirror", scene);
            mirror.material.backFaceCulling = false;
            // mirror.material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.0, 0, 0.1);
            mirror.material.reflectionTexture = new BABYLON.MirrorTexture("mirror", 512, scene, true);
            mirror.material.reflectionTexture.mirrorPlane = new BABYLON.Plane(0, -1.0, 0, -1.0);
            mirror.material.reflectionTexture.renderList = [ecran,sphere1];
            mirror.material.reflectionTexture.level = 1;
            //mirror.material.reflectionTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.PROJECTION_MODE;

           return scene;
        }


        var scene = createScene();

    var assetsManager = new BABYLON.AssetsManager(scene);
    var binaryTask = assetsManager.addBinaryFileTask("binary task", "index_subory/v.ogv");
    //engine.displayLoadingUI();
    engine.loadingUIText = "Loading... (Načítavanie...)";
    assetsManager.onTaskSuccess = function (task) {
            // Do something with task.data.
            //engine.hideLoadingUI();
        };
    assetsManager.onTaskError = function (task) {
            // Do something with task.data.
            alert('Error with loading by assetsManager...');                
        };
    assetsManager.onFinish = function (task) {
    //engine.hideLoadingUI();   
        engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
        scene.render();
        sphere1.rotation.y+=0.05;
        });
    };

    assetsManager.load();
        // Resize
        window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
            engine.resize();
        });
        }else{
            alert("Chyba: Nemôžem spustiť WebGL. (Error: Can't run WebGL.)");
        }
    </script>


</body></html>
```

This is my code used for preloading of the video with nice Loading message, then scene is presented.

Comment: Too long bit of code (boring)...can you update and post only the pertinent part pls ?